# Is it possible to add the_post_thumbnail to style.css?

Tags: post-thumbnails, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to add `the_post_thumbnail` location to style.css.

I'm using these images as backgrounds, and I can easily do that on the template, of course, but I'm thinking that for responsive design it would be way easier to simply add `the_post_thumbnail` location to style.css and then reference that location to serve the proper background to any given size instead of serving one giant image for (say) mobile devices.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: this question doesn't make much sense. CSS is static and the_post_thumbnail is dynamic, how can you even compare between them. If I didn't get correctly what you are asking for then maybe you should explain yourself better.

Comment: of course, I understand that. My question would be if there's a way to do it via PHP, some kind of code that replaces that part in css since css doesn't accept php code. Something like using <?php the post_thumbnail('whatever'); ?> only that in a css file ( not necessarily a css file, maybe using pure php in the header, or JQuery or whatever)

Comment: yes, it is possible and done all the time. If you still want a complete answer please modify the question to explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: seriously, if you understand the question and say "it's done all the time" I assume you have all the info needed. Thank you for your efforts and down votes tho, I'm looking for help on a legit question and thought this is a Q&A site, not a literature forum

Comment: What have you tried? What is your current code? Please **edit your question** to include your `the_post_thumbnail()` usage in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add background image you can do inline css in html

PHP:

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail())
{
    $desktop_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'desktop');
    $ipad_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'ipad');
    $mobile_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'mobile');

    $desktop = 'style="background: url('.$desktop_src[0].');"';
    $ipad = 'style="background: url('.$ipad_src[0].');"';
    $mobile = 'style="background: url('.$mobile_src[0].');"';

}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="desktop" <?php echo $desktop; ?>></div>
<div id="ipad" <?php echo $ipad; ?>></div>
<div id="mobile" <?php echo $mobile; ?>></div>
```

Comment: Yes Rahil, I was aware of that and it's similar to what I'm doing now, but this option would get only one version of the thumb. What I have is different sizes: 1 for desktop, 1 for ipad, 1 for mobile. If it was some static image, I could easily separate the styles like desktop--> background:imagedesktop.jpg ; ipad--> background:imageipad.jpg ; desktop--> background:imageipad.jpg  (and yes, I know this is not proper code, just explaining the logic). My current solution implies to add the code in the header based on screen size, but it's not elegant nor handy at all

Comment: (continues from above) and every time I need to do a change I need to change both CSS and templates, so I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this with not as much fuss as this

Comment: @Coco do you want to get all sizes image of current post?

Comment: yes, that's correct Rahil :)

Comment: @Coco see my edited answer hope it helps

Comment: Great! Can you please select this as a best answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: ah, you got it, thought it was just up voting it, thanx again